# Obfusticator cause exception to my j2me program - Error verifying method

Tags: java-me, proguard, midp, wma

After I Obfuscate my jar file I can install my jar file on the cell phone but it does not run! It gives me Exception:

```
Error verifying method mainPackage/mainClass notifyIncomingMessage(Ljavax/wireless/messaging/MessageConnection;)
```

I used ProGuard with just obfuscate option.
Do you have any idea about what is the cause of the problem?

This is what "Sony Erricson sdk" gives me after unsuccessful execution of my program:

```
    TRY(1): env: 0x12faa0, throwable: 0x12ffb0, tmpRootsCount: 0
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (2093048/2097152 bytes free)
TRY(2): env: 0x12f798, throwable: 0x1, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(2):   env: 0x12f798, throwable: 0x1, tmpRootsCount: 2
TRY(2): env: 0x12f7f0, throwable: 0x361f7a0, tmpRootsCount: 0
CATCH(2):   env: 0x12f7f0, throwable: 0x361f7a0, tmpRootsCount: 0
TRY(2): env: 0x12f7f8, throwable: 0x12f840, tmpRootsCount: 0
Initializing class: 'java/lang/System'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x2, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x2, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/cldc/i18n/Helper'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x23, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x23, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/File'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x15, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x15, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'java/lang/Math'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x8, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x8, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'java/lang/Double'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f6dc, throwable: 0x361fa04, tmpRootsCount: 2
Loading class 'com/sun/cldc/i18n/j2me/CP1256_Writer'
THROW(3):   env: 0x12f6dc, throwable: 0x361fa04, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f6dc, throwable: 0x361e9d4, tmpRootsCount: 2
THROW(2):   env: 0x12f7f8, throwable: 0x12f840, tmpRootsCount: 0
CATCH(2):   env: 0x12f7f8, throwable: 0x361e9d4, tmpRootsCount: 0
Exception: java/lang/ClassNotFoundException
TRY(2): env: 0x12f7f8, throwable: 0x361e9d4, tmpRootsCount: 0
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x1040e194, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x1040e194, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/kvem/cldc/i18n/j2me/GenericWriter'
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/main/Main'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x27, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x27, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/lcdui/Resource'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x1003d69f, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x1003d69f, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/security/SecurityToken'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x41, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x41, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/security/Permissions'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x2, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x2, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'javax/microedition/rms/RecordStore'
THROW(2):   env: 0x12f7f8, throwable: 0x361e9d4, tmpRootsCount: 0
CATCH(2):   env: 0x12f7f8, throwable: 0x361e220, tmpRootsCount: 0
Exception: java/lang/NullPointerException
TRY(2): env: 0x12f7f8, throwable: 0x361e220, tmpRootsCount: 0
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x47, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x47, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/io/j2me/http/Protocol'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x1e, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x1e, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'java/lang/Integer'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x48, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x48, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/io/j2me/https/Protocol'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x4a, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x4a, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/io/j2me/datagram/Protocol'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x64, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x64, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/io/NetworkConnectionBase'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x4b, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x4b, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/lcdui/DefaultInputMethodHandler'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x4d, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x4d, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/midlet/MIDletState'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f6e4, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f6e4, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/io/j2me/tcpobex/Protocol'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/io/j2me/irdaobex/Protocol'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/io/j2me/btgoep/Protocol'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/kvem/jsr082/impl/bluetooth/SecurityTokenHandler'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/kvem/io/j2me/tcpobex/Protocol'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
TRY(3): env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x2, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x2, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/mmedia/BasicPlayer'
Initializing class: 'com/sun/mmedia/JavaMPEG1Player2'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xba, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xba, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/kvem/DeviceConfiguration'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/io/j2me/push/PushRegistryImpl'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f6e4, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f6e4, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/kvem/jsr082/impl/JSR082PushAdaptor'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/io/j2me/mms/Protocol'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/io/j2me/jcrmi/Protocol'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xc0, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xc0, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/kvem/environment/NetMon'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
TRY(3): env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x2, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x2, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/j2me/global/AppResourceManagerFactory'
Initializing class: 'com/sun/j2me/global/DevResourceManagerFactory'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
TRY(3): env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x2, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x2, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/j2me/global/AppResourceBundleReader'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/amms/control/camera/SnapshotCtrl'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/mmedia/protocol/CommonDS'
THROW(2):   env: 0x12f7f8, throwable: 0x361e220, tmpRootsCount: 0
CATCH(2):   env: 0x12f7f8, throwable: 0x361c5f0, tmpRootsCount: 0
Exception: java/lang/ClassCastException
TRY(2): env: 0x12f7f8, throwable: 0x361c5f0, tmpRootsCount: 0
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/mmedia/MmapiTuner'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x93, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x93, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/mmedia/Configuration'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f6e4, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f6e4, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
TRY(3): env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x1010524e, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x1010524e, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/mmedia/DefaultConfiguration'
Initializing class: 'com/sun/mmedia/WtkQSoundAmmsConfig'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x2, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x2, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/mmedia/QSoundHiddenManager'
Exception: java/lang/NumberFormatException
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/mmedia/protocol/FileConnectionSubstitute'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x4f, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x4f, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/security/SecurityInitializer'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f6e4, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f6e4, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'javax/microedition/content/Registry'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/content/RegistryImpl'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xa0, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xa0, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/content/AppProxy'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/content/InvocationImpl'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/j2me/global/NormalizationTableImpl'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/j2me/global/CollationElementTableImpl'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
TRY(3): env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x2, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x2, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/j2me/payment/PaymentModule'
Initializing class: 'com/sun/kvem/payment/KvemPaymentModule'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x2, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x2, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/kvem/payment/CreditCardAdapter'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/perseus/platform/ResourceHandler'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f6e4, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f6e4, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/perseus/builder/DefaultFontFace'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/io/j2me/file/Protocol'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/kvem/jsr082/impl/bluetooth/SDDBStorageImpl'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f710, throwable: 0x1026d4dc, tmpRootsCount: 2
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/wma/WMASecurityInitializer'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x3, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x3, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/io/j2me/sms/Protocol'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x5, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x5, tmpRootsCount: 1
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xb3, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xb3, tmpRootsCount: 1
TRY(3): env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x1010524e, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x1010524e, tmpRootsCount: 1
TRY(3): env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x1010524e, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x1010524e, tmpRootsCount: 1
TRY(3): env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x1010524e, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x1010524e, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/io/Properties'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x5, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x5, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'javax/microedition/lcdui/Display'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xb3, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xb3, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/lcdui/Text'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x1003d69f, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x1003d69f, tmpRootsCount: 1
TRY(3): env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x1010524e, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x1010524e, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'javax/microedition/lcdui/Item'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xb2, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xb2, tmpRootsCount: 1
TRY(3): env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x1010524e, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f714, throwable: 0x1010524e, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'javax/microedition/lcdui/Displayable'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x4b, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x4b, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'javax/microedition/lcdui/Font'
Initializing class: 'javax/microedition/lcdui/Screen'
Initializing class: 'javax/microedition/lcdui/ImageItem'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xb3, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xb3, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/lcdui/DisplayDeviceAccess'
THROW(2):   env: 0x12f7f8, throwable: 0x361c5f0, tmpRootsCount: 0
CATCH(2):   env: 0x12f7f8, throwable: 0x3594a88, tmpRootsCount: 0
Exception: java/lang/NullPointerException
TRY(2): env: 0x12f7f8, throwable: 0x3594a88, tmpRootsCount: 0
Exception: java/lang/NullPointerException
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xd, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xd, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/midp/content/InvocationStore'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x1003d69f, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x1003d69f, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'javax/microedition/midlet/MIDletProxy'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x35957b4, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0x35957b4, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'javax/microedition/lcdui/List'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xb2, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xb2, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'javax/microedition/lcdui/ChoiceGroup'
TRY(3): env: 0x12f708, throwable: 0x361fa04, tmpRootsCount: 2
Loading class 'com/sun/cldc/i18n/j2me/CP1256_Writer'
THROW(3):   env: 0x12f708, throwable: 0x361fa04, tmpRootsCount: 2
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f708, throwable: 0x3593ba0, tmpRootsCount: 2
THROW(2):   env: 0x12f7f8, throwable: 0x3594a88, tmpRootsCount: 0
CATCH(2):   env: 0x12f7f8, throwable: 0x3593ba0, tmpRootsCount: 0
Exception: java/lang/ClassNotFoundException
TRY(2): env: 0x12f7f8, throwable: 0x3593ba0, tmpRootsCount: 0
TRY(3): env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xb4, tmpRootsCount: 1
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f728, throwable: 0xb4, tmpRootsCount: 1
Initializing class: 'com/sun/kvem/cldc/i18n/j2me/GenericReader'
Garbage collecting...
Collected 511776 bytes of garbage (2017472/2097152 bytes free)
TRY(3): env: 0x12f708, throwable: 0x361f81c, tmpRootsCount: 2
Loading class 'mainPackage/mainClass'
Garbage collecting...
Collected 3268 bytes of garbage (1950216/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (1946120/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (1944072/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (1942024/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (1939976/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (1937928/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (1935880/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (1933832/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (1931784/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 8144 bytes of garbage (1937880/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (1935832/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (1933784/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (1931736/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (1929688/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (1927640/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (1925592/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (1923544/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (1921496/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (1919448/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (1917400/2097152 bytes free)
Garbage collecting...
Collected 0 bytes of garbage (1915352/2097152 bytes free)
Class loaded ok
Linking class: 'mainPackage/mainClass'
Class linked ok
CATCH(3):   env: 0x12f708, throwable: 0x361f81c, tmpRootsCount: 2
Error verifying method mainPackage/mainClass notifyIncomingMessage(Ljavax/wireless/messaging/MessageConnection;)V
Method............: 1024a748 'com/sun/midp/midlet/MIDletState.createMIDlet (static)' 
Stack Chunk.......: 342102c
Frame Pointer.....: 3421084
Approximate bytecode offset 4: Inconsistent or missing stackmap at target
Current IP........: 1035d4e7 = 1035d4ca + offset 29

Previous Frame....: 342104c
Previous IP.......: 103f6e20 (offset 22)
Frame size........: 7 (1 arguments, 6 local variables)
Argument[0].......: 3421964
Local[1]..........: 0
Local[2]..........: 35909ec
Local[3]..........: 3432534
Local[4]..........: 3590a00
Local[5]..........: 1028f4ac
Local[6]..........: 35909cc
Operand[1]........: 361f7e0

Method............: 102b14c8 'com/sun/midp/midlet/Selector.run (virtual)' 
Stack Chunk.......: 342102c
Frame Pointer.....: 342104c
Current IP........: 103f6e20 = 103f6e0a + offset 22
Previous Frame....: 0
Previous IP.......: 1
Frame size........: 6 (1 arguments, 5 local variables)
Argument[0].......: 3421b68
Local[1]..........: 343261c
Local[2]..........: 3421964
Local[3]..........: 0
Local[4]..........: 0
Local[5]..........: 0
Operand[1]........: 343261c

VM status:
Instruction pointer.: 1035d4e7 (offset within invoking method: 29)
Next instruction....: 0x4c
Frame pointer.......: 3421084
Local pointer.......: 3421068
Stack size..........: 128; sp: 342109c; ranges: 3421034-3421234;
Contents of the current stack frame:
    3421068: 3421964 (lp)
    342106c: 0
    3421070: 35909ec
    3421074: 3432534
    3421078: 3590a00
    342107c: 1028f4ac
    3421080: 35909cc
    3421084: 342104c (fp)
    3421088: 103f6e20
    342108c: 3421064
    3421090: 1024a748
    3421094: 342102c
    3421098: 0 (end of frame)
    342109c: 361f7e0 (sp)
Execution stack contains 108 items: 
3421b68  
343261c  
3421964  
0  
0  
0  
0  
1  
35909d0  
102b14c8  
342102c  
0  
343261c  
3421964  
0  
35909ec  
3432534  
3590a00  
1028f4ac  
35909cc  
342104c  
103f6e20  
3421064  
1024a748  
342102c  
0  
361f7e0  

Execution completed.
3690964 bytecodes executed
285 thread switches
1770 classes in the system (including system classes)
19842 dynamic objects allocated (658096 bytes)
23 garbage collections (523188 bytes collected)
CATCH(2):   env: 0x12f7f8, throwable: 0x3593ba0, tmpRootsCount: 0
ALERT: java/lang/VerifyError: mainPackage/mainClass.
Execution completed.
3690964 bytecodes executed
285 thread switches
1770 classes in the system (including system classes)
19842 dynamic objects allocated (658096 bytes)
23 garbage collections (523188 bytes collected)
```

Comment: possibly related? http://stackoverflow.com/q/5701126/250725

Comment: on my nokia e66 it gives me "unhandled exception"! on sony erricson wtk emulator there is no any identified error but it does not run!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Inconsistent or missing stackmap at target" means that the preverification information inside a class file is incorrect.

Make sure that you specify `-microedition`, so ProGuard preverifies the code for JME, not JSE.

**Don't** specify `-dontpreverify`. You do want ProGuard to preverify the code. Alternatively, you could apply the external JME preverifier, but that is less efficient.

Cfr. ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Verification error](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#invalidclassexception2)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to not create your jar file with `javax` packages in it. `java` and `javax` must be available only by Virtual Machine classpath.

Comment: bu these type of packages are used! for examlple javax.microedition.location or javax.microedition.rms.RecordStore what can I do?

Comment: You can import javax packages during development because of the virtual machine classpath, but you can not export these packages with your application .class files.