# Proguard to obfuscate Android code with DNSJava library

Tags: android, proguard, dnsjava

I have an android app which has dnsjava.jar in the /libs/ directory of the project. Everything built fine and can be packaged into APK (without proguard).

However, when i introduced proguard into the project.properties (in eclipse), i get the following warnings:

```
[2013-03-07 14:16:08 - ] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-03-07 14:16:08 - ] Warning: org.xbill.DNS.spi.DNSJavaNameServiceDescriptor: can't find superclass or interface sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameServiceDescriptor
[2013-03-07 14:16:08 - ] Warning: org.xbill.DNS.spi.DNSJavaNameServiceDescriptor: can't find referenced class sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameService
[2013-03-07 14:16:08 - ] Warning: org.xbill.DNS.spi.DNSJavaNameServiceDescriptor: can't find referenced class sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameServiceDescriptor
[2013-03-07 14:16:08 - ] Warning: org.xbill.DNS.spi.DNSJavaNameServiceDescriptor: can't find referenced class sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameService
[2013-03-07 14:16:08 - ] Warning: org.xbill.DNS.spi.DNSJavaNameServiceDescriptor: can't find referenced class sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameService
[2013-03-07 14:16:08 - ]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-03-07 14:16:08 - ] Warning: there were 5 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-03-07 14:16:08 - ]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2013-03-07 14:16:08 - ] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-03-07 14:16:08 - ]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
```

Using -keep class org.xbill.** { *; } in proguard-project.txt does not seem to solve this.

Comment: Hi how you enable proguard settings to your App in eclipse........

Comment: Hmm, reading around, and found that adding a -dontwarn org.xbill.** seems to solve the problem. Heck...

Comment: Try adding the `-dontwarn` tag in your proguard.config file.

Comment: Also do not obfuscate the classes in which you are using library `dnsjava.jar` just keep it as it is like `-keep class sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameService { *; }`

Answer (score 5):

This is tested with proguard & DNSJava. Hope it helps. Copied from asmack readme

```
# This dnsjava class uses old Sun API
-dontnote org.xbill.DNS.spi.DNSJavaNameServiceDescriptor
-dontwarn org.xbill.DNS.spi.DNSJavaNameServiceDescriptor

# See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701126, happens in dnsjava
-optimizations !code/allocation/variable
```